# How delete all items with specific id?

Tags: android, realm

Android studio 3.2

```
public class Profile extend RealmObject {
  @PrimaryKey
  private long id;
}
```

I has `List<Profile> profileList;`
I this list I has 5 profiles with `id = 1, 2, ...`

Nice.

Now I need to delete from Realm profiles with `id=1 ,id=3, id=5`

So after delete the list must content only 2 profiles with `id=2 and id=4`

How I can do this?

P.S. The list of ids is a dynamic list. Today it has 3 ids , but tomorrow can 2 ids.

Comment: So are you trying to remove the profiles from the List, or delete them from Realm entirely?

Comment: I need to delete from Realm entirely.

Comment: how do you find out which IDs need to be deleted?

Comment: It's income as incoming params in method: something like this: myCustomDeleteMethod(List<Integer> idToDelete) {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that's actually quite simple, considering there's direct support for it...

```
r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
    realm.where(Profile.class).in("id", new Long[] { 1L, 3L, 5L }).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
});
```

See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#in-java.lang.String-java.lang.Long:A-

Answer (score 0):

As per the Realm documentation, you need to search for the all possible matches

```
// obtain the results of a query
final RealmResults<Profile> results = realm.where(Profile.class).equalTo("profile.id", 1).where().equalTo("profile.id", 3).where().equalTo("profile.id", 5).findAll();

// All changes to data must happen in a transaction
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        // remove single match
        results.deleteFirstFromRealm();
        results.deleteLastFromRealm();

        // remove a single object
        Dog dog = results.get(5);
        dog.deleteFromRealm();

        // Delete all matches
        results.deleteAllFromRealm();
    }
});
```

[Realm doc](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#deletion)

Comment: But this is a static way. But suppose the list of ids is dynamic. Today id=1,2,3, but tomorrow is may be 4,5.

Comment: Use a loop to add all criteria.

Comment: That RealmResults will just be an empty list. The conditions should be combined with `or()`. Chained querying is basically `and()`.